# Chips Selector Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have a list of sizes that I get from Firebase with java Android Studio and I want to make a size selector with chips, that is, a new chip is created for each size. example:

[image]

Chips o radio buttom

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.